# Transform week/year column into date format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I am trying to transform a column containing variables in 22/2022 format to datetime. Originally the variables were formatted as 202222 but I thought if I could formatt the date to 22/2022 it will be easier to transform to date time.

```
dff["week_id_mrc"]=dff["week_id_mrc"].astype(str)
dff[['week_convert']] = dff[['week_id_mrc']].applymap(str).applymap(lambda s: "{}/{}{}".format(s[4:6],s[6:], s[0:4]))
dff['week_date'] = dff['week_convert'] + "-1"
dff["week_date"] = pd.to_datetime(dff["week_date"],format='%U-%Y-%w')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this dataframe:

```
   week_date
0     202222
```

---

Then you can do (`0` means Sunday):

```py
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["week_date"].astype(str) + "0", format="%Y%W%w")
```

Prints:

```
   week_date       date
0     202222 2022-06-05
```

---

If you want the date from Monday, then change `0` to `1`:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["week_date"].astype(str) + "1", format="%Y%W%w")
```

Prints:

```
   week_date       date
0     202222 2022-05-30
```